# Rails gem 'nested_form_fields' doesn't work in the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I'm using 'nested_form_fields' gem to build Rails form. It does work but not in the right way.

When I click the delete button, the fields are all deleted at once. 
(When I add three text_fields, and try to delete one of them, all fields are deleted at once and there's a new text_field with nothing entered.)

How can I change it, to delete only the specific field that delete button is clicked, and others just keep remained?

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <%= form_for(recipe) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name, 'Title' %>
      <%= f.text_area :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder:'Enter Recipe Title' %>
      <%= f.label :name, 'Comment' %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'about the Recipe' %>
      <%= f.label :name, 'Volume' %>
      <%= f.number_field :volume, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter integer number of volume' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Ingredient</th>
            <th>amount</th>
          </tr>
          <%= f.nested_fields_for :ingredients, wrapper_tag: :tr do |q| %>
          <div>
            <td><%= q.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder:'Enter Ingredient name' %></td>
            <td><%= q.text_field :amount, class: 'form-control', placeholder:'Enter amount' %></td>
          </div>
            <td class="col-xs-1">
              <button type="button" class="close form-control" aria-label="Close"><%= q.remove_nested_fields_link %></button>
            </td>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :ingredients, 'Add field', class: 'btn', role: 'button' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Instractions</th>
          </tr>
          <%= f.nested_fields_for :instractions, wrapper_tag: :tr, class: ' fields row' do |q| %>
            <td class="col-xs-11">
              <%= q.text_field :content, class: 'form-control', placeholder:'Enter Instraction' %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-1">
              <button type="button" class="close form-control" aria-label="Close"><%= q.remove_nested_fields_link %></button>
            </td>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <%= f.add_nested_fields_link :instractions, 'Add field', class: 'btn', role: 'button' %>
    </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Model

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :instractions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :instractions, allow_destroy: true
end

class Instraction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
end

class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
    @recipe.ingredients.build
    @recipe.instractions.build
  end

  def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
      flash[:success] = 'Recipe Posted'
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Sorry, Failed to post.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: okay I've got the answer for this problem. I should have loaded jQuery first before bootstrap, and also add '//= require jquery_ujs' to application.js. now it seems working correctly.